# Is $a_xx^m+b_yy^n+c_zz^k$ reducible, for $m,n,k \geq 2$ over $k[x,y,z]$ for a field of characteristic $0$, where $a_x,b_y,c_z \in \{-1,1\}$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $a_xx^m+b_yy^n+c_zz^r \in k[x,y,z]$ for $m,n,r \geq 2$, where we let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and $a_x,b_y,c_z \in \{-1,1\}$. Can such a polynomial be reducible over $k[x,y,z]$, that is, written as the product of two non-constant polynomials?

For example: We know that $x^2+y^2-z^2$ is *not* reducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, since it would then have to be written on the form (I believe) $(ax+by+cz+d)(ex+fy+gz+h) = aex^2+afxy+agxz+axh+beyx+bfy^2+bgyz+bhy+cexz+cfyz+cgz^2+chz+dex+dfy+dgz+dh = aex^2+bfy^2+cgz^2+\underbrace{(af+be)xy}_{xy = yx} + (ag+ce)xz+(bg+cf)yz+chz+dex+dfy+dgz+dh$.

We find that $ae = 1 \iff a = \frac{1}{e}$ and $bf = 1 \iff f = \frac{1}{b}$ which gives us that $af+be = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2+b^2}{ba} = 0 \implies a = b = 0$, which is a contradiction (assuming the polynomial was reducible).

Could someone provide an example where it can be reduced. If a polynomial on said form, under the given conditions, can not be reduced, I would be interested to see a proof.